# How do I load different custom pins or identifiers based off of their property values?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have an array of objects that conform to `<MKAnnotation>`.
I load this array into my annotations using addAnnotations:.

In the method:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:    
(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

I have every pin load a custom image using:

```
annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"purp_pin.png"];
```

However, I don't want all the pins to load with this image. I want it to load a different custom image/identifier depending on the properties the object that conformed to `<MKAnnotation>` had.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have some custom property in your object that conforms to `MKAnnotation`, one way you can access it in `viewForAnnotation` to set the image is like this:

```
MyAnnotationClass *myAnnot = (MyAnnotationClass *)annotation;

if (myAnnot.someProperty == 42)
    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"purp_pin.png"];
else
    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"];
```

Make sure the `image` property is set regardless of whether annotation view is being dequeued or created.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I didn't know I had to cast it like that. Makes a lot of sense to me now =)